# Domain folder pointing to other IP/Server as the real domain

Tags: apache-2.2, redirect

I have following situation:

I have a site `domain.com`, which is pointing to `Server1` . `domain.com/search/`, should point to `Server2`, but the URL in the address bar should't be changed. The user should think that it is the same site.

How do I implement something like this?

Answer (score 1):

There's no way you can do this without the traffic going through the first server.  You can use some type of proxying system (most webservers have one built in).

Answer (score -1):

You may be able to use an Apache rewrite rule to redirect search to server2 but its not clear to me how you would mask the resulting URL.

Comment: By using a reverse proxy, either directly or through a rewriterule with the [P] flag appended.